# Is it possible to apply modifiers changes to several objects at once?

Tags: modifiers, linked-data

I have a series of objects that all use the same series of modifiers.
When I select a bunch of them, and change a modifier, I expect it to propagate to all the objects, and instead it only applies to the last one.
Linking the objects in this regard is not possible, only copy/paste of modifiers is possible, so how is one supposed to do this?
What really puzzles me is why it's not possible to link all the objects modifiers to a single source like it happens in example with materials!

Comment: I fully feel your puzzlement, [linked modifiers](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/g0bbbc/) would make sense :))

Comment: Man this proposal is 3 years old and only 38 votes... people are not so keen on automation unluckily... it's terrible.

Comment: I believe you have a situation where holding the ALT key while making the change will cause it to be applied to all of the selected objects at once.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @MartyFouts oh gosh you are my saver!!! Hoe can I offer you a beer?

Comment: You can click on the button to [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on the answer I just added. It helps me gather reputation and it lets other people know your problem is solved.

Comment: Sure, I was waiting for you to post it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select all of the objects
- As you perform the action hold the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key.

This doesn't always work but there are many operations for which it does.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

*Copy to Selected*: Copy the modifier from the active object to all selected objects.

[image]

**PS:** I think it's only in newer version of *Blender* so try upgrading to one if this option does not apear.

Comment: Eh unluckily no. I need to deactivate/reactivate a modifier in the viewport on several objects at once and each time I'm wasting a lot of time doing it manually on each one... it doesn't make any sense in my opinion that this can't be linked like materials. Thank you for the effort though.

Comment: Oh no. Weel if I remeber anything else I'll update the answer.

Comment: I guess the right way to go for this now is the geometry nodes construction.